# what is wrong with this rspec failure code

Tags: rspec

This is my first question here, and I'm actually asking because I'm desperate and my course's mentor is away...I'm following a web development course and ran into this problem in unit testing using RSpec...the command line I'm using is rspec spec/models (and the file in that folder is: product_spec.rb). This is the code I'm using to test:

```
    require 'rails_helper'

    describe Product do

        context "when the Product has comments" do

            before do
                @product = Product.create(:name => "product model")
            end
        end

        context "when user has email & password" do

            before do
                @user = User.create(:email => "testspec@test.com", :password => "passtheword")
            end
        end



    context "create comment 1" do

        before do
            @product.comments.create(:rating => 1, :user => @user, :body => "Awful comment!")
        end
    end

    context "create comment 2" do

        before do
            @product.comments.create(:rating => 3, :user => @user, :body => "another awful comment!")
        end
    end

    context "create coment 3" do

        before do
            @product.comments.create(:rating => 5, :user => @user, :body => "yet another awful comment!")
        end
    end

    context "rating average" do
        before { @average_rating = Product.comments.count(:rating) }
        it "returns the average rating" do
            expect(@average_rating).to eq 3
        end
    end

    end
```

And this is the error I'm getting from RSpec:

```
    F

    Failures:

      1) Product rating average returns the average rating
         Failure/Error: before { @average_rating = Product.comments.count(:rating) }

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `comments' for #<Class:0x007fe22e58b6d8>
 # ./spec/models/product_spec.rb:43:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00099 seconds (files took 1.61 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/product_spec.rb:44 # Product rating average returns the average rating
```

I even tried declaring the 'comments' as so:

```
context "register comment" do
  before do
    @comments = @product.comments
  end
end
```

But this didn't make any difference. Any help on this matter will be GREATLY appreciated as I'm going crazy and spent the past 3 days smashing stuff in the vicinity of the computer!! The next thing would be to smash the computer itself!!
Thanks a lot for reading. Hope you're having a nice day.

Comment: Oh!! Forgot to add, that I should be testing for the average rating of the submitted comments, but not to complicate matters, at this stage I would be happy if the code returns how many comments/ratings have been submitted; hence the =3 is still valid, since rating 1 + 3 + 5 / 3, still gives out 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without understanding your domain, model associations etc it's hard to be really clear. However it seems that your main issue here is the use of the context blocks.

In each of these context blocks `context "create comment 1" do` you set a context, use a before block to setup your test and then close the context block. Each of these blocks are distinct from each other and as they are currently written have no purpose - as there is no expectation to test against in any of them.

```
context "rating average" do
  ##This sets up your test within this context block.
  before do
    Product.comments.create(:rating => 1, :user => @user, :body => "Awful comment!")
    Product.comments.create(:rating => 3, :user => @user, :body => "another awful comment!")
    Product.comments.create(:rating => 5, :user => @user, :body => "yet another awful comment!")
  end

   ##Now lets test it.
   let(:average_rating) { Product.comments.count(:rating) }

   it "returns the average rating" do
     expect(average_rating).to eq 3
   end
end
```

The code may well not be correct but should show more clearly how you want to structure your tests. It is likely that you will need to tweak this further.

The following code takes similar example of restaurants and reviews which can be likened to products and comments/ratings:

````
##In this example we need to create some users to create our restaurants and then reviews so use RSpec's ```let``` which is lazily evaluated.
let(:user) { User.create(email: "test@test.com", password: "password" }
let(:user2) { User.create(email: "test2@test.com", password: "passwordpass2" }

##Then we test (and also set up the conditions within the test itself).
context '1 review' do
  it 'returns that rating' do
    restaurant = user.restaurants.create(name: 'BK Lounge')
    restaurant.build_review({"thoughts" => "Great!", "rating" => 4}, user).save
    expect(restaurant.average_rating).to eq 4
  end
end

context 'multiple reviews' do
  it 'returns the average' do
    restaurant = user.restaurants.create(name: 'BK Lounge')
    restaurant.build_review({"thoughts" => "Not great!", "rating" => 1}, user).save
    restaurant.build_review({"thoughts" => "Great!", "rating" => 5}, user2).save
    expect(restaurant.average_rating).to eq 3
  end
end
````

It's worth noting that these tests could be heavily refactored making of either `let` or `before` or even using tools such as `FactoryGirl` to create our objects for testing but should provide a useful example for solving your issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and help; I really appreciated it very much. Although it didn't manage to fix the problem, I still managed to understand perfectly how it was working...the way you laid it down, it became almost instantaneously evident where I was getting these recurring problems.

Comment: The only reason why it didn't fix the problem, was because I was doing a very stupid mistake, and not checking with the models' validations!!!! There were 4 objects to be validated and I was only giving it 1...doh!!!! Thanks a lot for your time Mr. Hawker; really greatly appreciated!! Hope you're having a nice day :)